# glBlitFramebuffer with QOpenGLFunctions

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qt5

I'm learning to use OpenGL with Qt5's [QOpenGLFunctions class](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qopenglfunctions.html).
I don't see glBlitFramebuffer as a member either in that class or in the global namespace.

Do I have to get check for the extension and get the procedure address manually or did I just miss it?

If it's not supported is there a good implementation available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

inherit from **QOpenGLFunctions_3_0**,and call **initializeOpenGLFunctions()**

if you failed when call **initializeOpenGLFunctions()**,maybe need to set version like this:

```
QGLFormat glf = QGLFormat::defaultFormat();
glf.setVersion(3,0);
QGLFormat::setDefaultFormat(glf);
```